# MSSQL replace with concatenation on parameters - Syntax error

Tags: sql-server, replace, syntax, parameters, concatenation

I am trying to write a stored procedure that concatenates a comma as a prefix to a parameter within the REPLACE function like this:

```
update [SQSDBA].[M_PARAMSTRINGS] set PARAMCHAR = REPLACE([PARAMCHAR], ',' + @CurrentCompanyCode, ',' + @NewCompanyCode)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ChangeCompanyPrefix, Line 248
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

How should I do it?

Comment: can you post the entire code of the procedure `ChangeCompanyPrefix`? Specifically line 248

Comment: @ughai. Line 248 is what I included above. The only other part relevant to that update statement is the declaration of the parameters. `@CurrentCompanyCode as varchar(3),
 @NewCompanyCode as varchar (3)`

Comment: You may not think it is relevant, but a missing parentheses somewhere (or similar) can throw you off when tracking the error, as the actual line indicated as the error is much later on than the original error.

Comment: check the values for @CurrentCompanyCode and @NewCompanyCode has any special character `'` for example

Comment: @GarethD I have proven that it is the line above through commenting out all the rest of the procedure and only leaving the update statement in question.

Comment: @Deepshikha - I am getting this error when I try and alter the stored procedure, so this is not when I am trying to execute it, therefore the parameters are not being set.

Comment: @Scare-d-cat - your update statement looks correct. i think the error might be coming due to something else in the procedure. can you confirm that after commenting out only this update statement, the procedure compiles?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your update statement in its current form, here is a working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c9b54/1) with your update statement. If you don't want to post your full procedure that is fine, but if you want help with your problem then I would suggest you do.

Comment: I made a mini-version of the stored procedure and get the exact same issue. Here is the full code:

`CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestChangeCompanyPrefix
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @CurrentCompanyCode as varchar(3),
 @NewCompanyCode as varchar (3)
 
AS
BEGIN


update [SQSDBA].[M_PARAMSTRINGS] 
set PARAMCHAR = REPLACE([PARAMCHAR], ',' + @CurrentCompanyCode, ',' + @NewCompanyCode)


GO`

Comment: there is no `END` at the end before `GO` corresponding to your `AS BEGIN`

Comment: @GarethD - I do get the same error when I try a SQL fiddle with that stored procedure [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c9b54/2)

Comment: @ughai - Thanks! You are right. It was the missing END :)